# Python reading csv into dict

Tags: python, csv

Im having trouble reading my dict in 'paReference'.

[image]

here is 123.csv:

```
BrandName,LineCode,PartNo,ShortDescription,SuperStock,DropshipStock,Price,Core
Carter,5C,M3643,FILTER,0,0,14.8,0
Carter,5C,M3805,FILTER,1,0,14.8,0
Carter,5C,M4512,FILTER,2,0,14.8,0
Carter,5C,M4642,FILTER,3,0,14.8,0
Carter,5C,M60088,FILTER,4,0,14.8
Carter,5C,M60142,FILTER,6,0,14.8
Carter,5C,M60167,FILTER,7,0,14.8,0
```

and abc.csv:

```
productcode,book_isbn,stockstatus,Price,Core,AddtoCartBtn_Replacement_Text,Availability
5CM2195,5CM2195,,,,,
5CM2846,5CM2846,,,,,
5CM3643,5CM3643,,,,,
5CM3805,5CM3805,,,,,
5CM4512,5CM4512,,,,,
5CM4642,5CM4642,,,,,
5CM60088,5CM60088,,,,,
5CM60142,5CM60142,,,,,
5CM60167,5CM60167,,,,,
```

Am I reading the csv into the paRefefence dict improperly?

```
c = csv.reader(open(pluginPath + "123.csv"))
d = csv.reader(open(pluginPath + "abc.csv"))

paReference ={}
for item in c:
    if item[1] not in paReference:
        paReference =[item[0]] = [item[1] + item[2].replace('-','')]
    else:
        paReference[item[1]].append(item[0])
    print(item)

for item in d:
    if item[0] not in paReference:
        print ("Not Found! " + item[0])
    else:
        print ("Found! " + item[0])
```

Im new to python I'm having trouble understanding why it has found one part number but not the others. Any suggestions help!

Comment: `paReference =[item[0]] = [item[1] + item[2].replace('-','')]` is almost certainly not doing what you want.  What did you want it to do?

Comment: You have an extra equal sign that is going to mess up your code in the first `if` clause here: `paReference =[item[0]] = [item[1] + item[2].replace('-','')]`

Comment: use `csv.DictReader` rather than creating your dictionary if you want to read in a key/value pair container https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: Ah yes I see that now. But untilamtely I am trying to concatenate LineCode and Part number and use THAT as a reference for d ('abc.csv').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `productcode` from the 2nd csv is the `LineCode` plus `PartNo` from the first csv.  It looks like you are checking the `productcode` against the keys of the dictionary you built.  It also looks like you are using the productcode as the keys and the brand name as the value?  If that is the case, this should work.

```
paReference = {}
for item in c:
    pcode = item[1] + item[2].replace('-','')
    if pcode not in paReference:
        paReference[pcode] = [item[0]]
    else:
        paReference[pcode].append(item[0])
    print(item)

for item in d:
    if item[0] not in paReference:
        print ("Not Found! " + item[0])
    else:
        print ("Found! " + item[0])
```

If this is not your intended use, post a comment.

Comment: Ah yes! awesome thank you so much! Makes total sense now.